# What is a JavaScript 'element' within the context of jQuery library OpenSeaDragon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, openseadragon

I'm using a pretty cool JavaScript/jQuery library called OpenSeaDragon. It's for displaying deep zoom images. It also have a method for adding 'overlays', essentially creating a div and putting it over the image with coordinates though a viewer object. There's also a method for removing the overlays: https://openseadragon.github.io/docs/OpenSeadragon.Viewer.html#removeOverlay

```
viewer.removeOverlay(element or element id);
```

As the doc states regarding the input param: "A reference to the element or an element id which represent the ovelay content to be removed." I'm creating a whole bunch of overlays -- creating a grid out of rectangles -- so I've given them a class. Passing the class to this method doesn't work. So I'm trying to understand what they mean by "element". Is there a way I can use JQuery or JavaScript to select an "element" and pass it to the method? Or some such thing?

thanks

Comment: usually  `element` means a DOM node, sp e.g using jQuery: `$('.myClass')[0]` for first matched element in jq set

Comment: Just checking DOC, you surely call `viewer.addOverlay(element, etc...)`. So pass to `viewer.removeOverlay()` method same element. And ya, `element` refers to a DOM node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It usually means an element in your document, i.e. a DOM node. So, a `div`, or a `span`, or somesuch.

You can select an element with jQuery pretty easily:

```
var $obj = $('#elementId');
```

and then grab the underlying DOM node from the jQuery object that results:

```
var elm = $obj[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. Here's how to do it:

```
var n = $(".gridcell").length
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    viewer.removeOverlay($(".gridcell")[0]);
}
```

At first I though I could iterate through the array, calling removeOverlay() on each item index successively. This was causing half the overlays to be deleted on each run. So, for 16 overlay, I have to run it 4 times. After a few minutes it clicked... Each time you get the elements $(".gridcell"), it returns a new array.

Comment: uh yeah I'd get all the elements into their own array before you do any remove-iteration